# Save game state in OnPause or OnSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-activity

I am a newbie to `Android`, and I am developing a simple maze game for educational purposes.
I am confused how should I react to the `OnSaveInstanceState` and `OnPause` callbacks.
Basically I want to save the state of the game, so when there is an orientation change or the user presses back button, the game should be resumed from the saved state.

I have read that there is no guarantee that `OnSaveInstanceState` will be called. Then why should I use it all? I am confused.

Which callback should I use for saving the game state? Should I use only `OnPause` and save the game state to a file in the internal storage of the device?

How would you tackle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `onPause()` and `onSaveInstanceState()` is that the latter is not part of the `Activity`'s lifecycle. While you do have the guarantee that `onPause()` is called in every situation, that's not true for `onSaveInstanceState()`. As per documentation persistent data should be saved on `onPause()`. For instance during normal navigation between `Activity`ies, the pair `onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState` is not called

Comment: I consider game state persistent data? So I should use onPause method. Is it acceptable to serialize the GameState object to a file in the internal storage?

Comment: Imo yes it is, but probably you'll find people that could argue about this decision. Of course that depends also on the game's constraints

Comment: @Blackbelt  I was wondering if you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/d5opg5 . It's not one of those "fix-this-for-me" questions, I promise.